# Fontconfig error - "out of memory"

Tags: command-line, fonts

I am trying to launch the Android Studio on Xubuntu. When I type ./studio.sh in terminal I get this error:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 14: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 23: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 32: out of memory
```

BUT the android studio launches and it seems to work without any problems. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a bug in Khmer fonts, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-khmeros/+bug/1254967.

If it bothers you and you do not need Khmer fonts, you can get rid of it removing (with configuration) the fonts:

```
apt-get purge  fonts-khmeros-core
```

If you need the fonts, there are various workarounds in the aforementioned bug. The most correct way seems to edit the failing file and remove the `<match>` and `</match>` tags, as explained here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.bugs.general/1095401

Comment: Thanks. Who needs this font? ;)  
I had never heard of it before. Just removed it.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-khmeros/+bug/1254967/comments/6), installing the latest DEB for this package (the Khmer OS font) from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-khmeros/+bug/1254967/comments/6) also solves the issue. Looks like the bug was resolved for Trusty, but was never backported to the Saucy repository.

Broadly speaking, the "error message" is just a symptom while actual functionality that breaks/misbehaves is the root cause. By uninstalling the package, we are fixing the symptom while getting rid of the functionality itself.

Comment: still got this error when upgrading to 14.04 from 13.10. So it seems it is **NOT REALLY** resolved for Trusty.

Comment: Got the same error to when upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04