# How do I open ubuntu 12.04 from safe mode?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, server

I was updating my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. After this, when I restart my Ubuntu then it doesn't open. I get an error on black screen. Error is given below:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 14: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 23: out of memory
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 32: out of memory
```

What can I do now? I am worried because it doesn't allow me to boot in. Yet now I can solve my all problems relating Ubuntu via terminal. But now its first time for me. Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: This error occurs due to the Khmer fonts. You can refer the url to resolve this error. http://askubuntu.com/questions/421891/fontconfig-error-out-of-memory

Answer (score 0):

for booting  in ubuntu without gui hold shift until the grub menu shows

and then edit the os option by pressing e

from

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=d07e0c99-65ba-4eda-98d8-79693dc79554 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7

to

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=d07e0c99-65ba-4eda-98d8-79693dc79554 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 3

where 3 stands for the runlevel 3 and there are runlevels from 0 to 6 , and the os boots in the terminal