# Boot in failed. Shows Fontconfig error

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, upgrade, fonts

After an unsuccessful upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04, I am not allowed to login as it shows a black screen with message beginning with

```
Fontconfig error:"etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf", line 14: out of memory.
```

How do i resolve this?

There are no other boot partitions on this system. No windows.

EDIT
After removing the font as suggested. Fontconfig warnings are displayed

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf",       line 9: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected

Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected

Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-loma-synthetic.conf", line 12: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 26: Having multiple in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 31: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 40: Having multiple values in isn't supported and may not work as expected
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fontconfig error - "out of memory"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/421891/fontconfig-error-out-of-memory)

Comment: `apt-get purge  fonts-khmeros-core`

Comment: -very new to linux-. Tried that. Says "the package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."

Answer (score 0):

Switch to tty1 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge fonts-khmeros-core
```

It's a old bug and I assume, you don't need this font **;)**

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.:(

Comment: @PB and the error from your comment above?

Comment: that being gone, now it says "Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf"

Comment: @PB My answer resolves your problem, if you have additionally problems after that, please ask a new question **;)**. That would be fair and is good for your reputation.